# serve assets file with invaid names with nginx

Tags: wordpress, nginx, wget, static-files

I have download a full wordpress website with below command:

```
wget -r --convert-links --no-parent website_url
```

I want to server this site with `nginx` but there is a problem.

some of files has an invalid names with version like `js_composer_front.min.js?ver=6.0.5` and `nginx` throw 404.
how can I solve this problem?

Comment: you can try add `try_files $uri $uri/ =404;` on location block

Comment: I tried this.It throw 404 always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't fix the mentioned issue with Nginx and Wget, you should write script to modify generated links, maybe sed or python script.
I think the better solution is to use [simply-static](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simply-static/) plugin.